# How does the inline assembly in this compare-exchange function work? (%H modifier on ARM)

Tags: gcc, arm, inline-assembly, compare-and-swap

```
static inline unsigned long long __cmpxchg64(unsigned long long *ptr,unsigned long long old,unsigned long long new)
{
    unsigned long long oldval;
    unsigned long res;
    prefetchw(ptr);
    __asm__ __volatile__(
"1: ldrexd      %1, %H1, [%3]\n"
"   teq     %1, %4\n"
"   teqeq       %H1, %H4\n"
"   bne     2f\n"
"   strexd      %0, %5, %H5, [%3]\n"
"   teq     %0, #0\n"
"   bne     1b\n"
"2:"
    : "=&r" (res), "=&r" (oldval), "+Qo" (*ptr)
    : "r" (ptr), "r" (old), "r" (new)
    : "cc");
    return oldval;
}
```

I find in gnu manual (extend extended-asm) that 'H' in '%H1' means 'Add 8 bytes to an offsettable memory reference'.

But I think if I want to load double word long data to oldval (a long long value), it should be add 4 bytes to the '%1' which is the low 32 bits of oldval as the high 32 bits of oldval. So what is my mistake?

Comment: I edited the title.  It seems like your real question isn't "what does __cmpxchg mean" but "how does this particular compare-exchange function work".  Please feel free to edit again if that is not what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I find in gnu manual(extend extended-asm) that 'H' in '%H1' means 'Add 8 bytes to an offsettable memory reference'.

[That table of template modifiers](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#x86-Operand-Modifiers) is for x86 only.  It is not applicable to ARM.

The template modifiers for ARM are unfortunately not documented in the GCC manual ([though they are for AArch64](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#AArch64-Operand-Modifiers)), but they are defined in the [armclang manual](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/100067/0611/armclang-Inline-Assembler/Inline-assembly-template-modifiers/Template-modifiers-for-AArch32-state?lang=en) and GCC conforms to those definitions as far as I can tell.  So the correct meaning of the `H` template modifier here is:

> The operand must use the r constraint, and must be a 64-bit integer or floating-point type. The operand is printed as the highest-numbered register holding half of the value.

Now this makes sense.  Operand 1 to the inline asm is `oldval` which is of type `unsigned long long`, 64 bits, so the compiler will allocate two consecutive 32-bit general purpose registers for it.  Let's say they are  `r4` and `r5` as in [this compiled output](https://godbolt.org/z/z88dKvPM5).  Then `%1` will expand to `r4`, and `%H1` will expand to `r5`, which is exactly what the `ldrexd` instruction needs.  Likewise, `%4, %H4` expanded to `r2, r3`, and `%5, %H5` expanded to `fp, ip`, which are [alternative names](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0040/d/ch06s02s01) for `r11, r12`.

The answer by frant explains what a compare-exchange is supposed to do.  (The spelling `cmpxchg` might come from the mnemonic for the x86 compare-exchange instruction.)  And if you read through the code now, you should see that it does exactly that.  The `teq; teqeq; bne` between `ldrexd` and `strexd` will abort the store if `old` and `*ptr` were unequal. And the `teq; bne` after `strexd` will cause a retry if the exclusive store failed, which happens if there was an intervening access to `*ptr` (by another core, interrupt handler, etc).  That is how atomicity is ensured.

Comment: `prefetchw` is also the name of an x86 instruction; smells a lot like it was ported from x86 code.  I expect you'd get equally good asm from C compilers for `compare_exchange_strong` on an `_Atomic long long`, if you enable `-mcpu` or `-march` options so they know that `ldrexd` is supported.  (But the question about the `%H` modifier is still relevant.)